# Create Batches from a stack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struggling to get my head around this but basically trying to create a list of batches of for example `1-200`, `201-400`, `401-53` from a number value of `453`.

So far I am able to split the number `453` into a list of `200`,`200`,`53` which basically tells me I need to create 3 batches.

However, am not sure on how to create the Batches?

Here is my code so far of creating the stacks

```
public List<int> CreateStacks(Int32 number, Int32 stackSize)
{
    List<int> stacks = new List<int>();
    int d = number / stackSize;
    if (d == 0)
    {
        return stacks;
    }
    int r = number % stackSize;

    string str = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("200", d));
    if (number % 100 > 0)
    {
        str = str + ", " + r;
        foreach(var s in str.Split(',').ToList())
        {
            stacks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
        }                
    }
    return stacks;
}
```

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: I am confused. How do you define a "range"? And how is it supposed to be used?

Comment: Unrelated to former questions: What if `satckSize` != 200 ? ... don't use "magic numbers".

Comment: won't your list in your example just contain `200, 200`? Where do you add the left over value to your stack? Why convert between string to int to simply convert the int again to a number? Why not simply use an `for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) { stacks.Add( stackSize ); } if (number % stackSize != 0) { stacks.Add( number % stackSize ); }`?

Comment: @Icepickle you are incorrect. The list contains `200`,`200`,`53`. `int r = number % stackSize;` which gives me remainder i.e. last number of the stacks gets joined to variable str.

Comment: @Kevin you are correct, very unreadable code, though

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 453).Batch(200)` https://morelinq.github.io/2.9/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a second method called `CreateRanges()` which produces the output you provided, with the exception of all ranges starting from one. Each range should start with zero or one; in your example the first batch would actually have 201 items.

```
// Stacks: 200, 200, 53
// Ranges: <1,200>, <201,400>, <401,453>

void Main()
{
    var stacks = CreateStacks(453, 200);
    Console.WriteLine("Stacks: " + string.Join(", ", stacks.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray()));
    var ranges = CreateRanges(453, stacks);
    Console.WriteLine("Ranges: " + string.Join(", ", ranges.Select(t => $"<{t.Item1},{t.Item2}>").ToArray()));
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public static List<Tuple<int, int>> CreateRanges(Int32 number, List<int> stacks)
{
    var ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var stack in stacks){
        ranges.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(index + 1, stack + index));
        index += stack;
    }
    return ranges;
}

public static List<int> CreateStacks(Int32 number, Int32 stackSize)
{
    List<int> stacks = new List<int>();
    int d = number / stackSize;
    if (d == 0)
    {
        return stacks;
    }
    int r = number % stackSize;

    string str = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("200", d));
    if (number % 100 > 0)
    {
        str = str + ", " + r;
        foreach (var s in str.Split(',').ToList())
        {
            stacks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
        }
    }
    return stacks;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dan Wilson for your solution. That worked as required :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop and determine if the count has reached 200 and then create a new List.

```
int total = 453;
int batchCount = 200;
List<List<int>> batches = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    if (i % batchCount == 0)
    {
        batches.Add(new List<int>());
    }

    batches[batches.Count -1].Add(i);
}
```

The List `batches` will contain 3 Lists of `int` with all the numbers.

Comment: I believe the OP just wants to know how to divide 453 in blocks of 200, so he gets 2 times 200 and once 53 (although his code doesn't reflect that)

Comment: Ah, that could also be the case. But he says "create a list of batches", so I based my answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

My shot, taking "create a list of batches" literally:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var batches = Batchify( 453, 200);
        Console.WriteLine(batches.Count);
        foreach( Batch batch in batches )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", batch.Start, batch.End);
        }
    }

    public static List<Batch> Batchify( int number, int size)
    {
        List<Batch> result = new List<Batch>();

        int running = number;
        int startIndex = 0;

        do
        {
            int endIndex = running < size ? startIndex+running : startIndex+size-1;
            result.Add(new Batch{ Start = startIndex, End = endIndex });
            startIndex = endIndex+1;
            running -= size;
        }while(running > 0);

        return result;
    }
}

public class Batch
{
    public int Start{get;set;}
    public int End{get;set;}
}
```

In action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oqFmv0